# X509Certificate2 publickey only Error: Cannot find the requested object

Tags: .net, jwt, x509certificate2, asp.net-core-6.0

So I'm trying use .Net 6.0 Auth 2.0 to authenticate a jwt token from an external issuer.
I have the public key of that issuer and am trying to use X509Certficate2 for the key as thats what they originally used for encoding the token;

But every time I try run it by giving the pem file path (which is in the same directory as the file calling for it) I get this error

[image]

We have so far tried everything we can think of, make sure the file exist and can be access by the code, using absolute paths, turning the file into type .cer, and more.
Now I only have access to the public key. And encase needed it RS256 encoded.

Comment: You can try to use File.ReadAllText method to read the pem file, then convert the based64 string, after that create the certificate, code like this: `var certPem = "MIIB3...aC"; //use File.ReadAllText read the pem file content.
var cert = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(certPem)); var certWithKey = cert.CopyWithPrivateKey(key); //combine the certificate with its private key` Or you can use the CreateFromPem(), code like this: `var certPem = File.ReadAllText("cert.pem");
var eccPem = File.ReadAllText("ecc.pem"); var cert = X509Certificate2.CreateFromPem(certPem, eccPem);`

Comment: @ZhiLv we tried the first one already even took the base64 portion into appsettings as a string, But to make sure i tried your exact first example but it still didn't work, it didn't working, and I'm a little confused where did the eccPem file come from?

Comment: Does the PEM say `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`, or something else?

Comment: Check the [CreateFromPem(ReadOnlySpan<Char>, ReadOnlySpan<Char>) method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.createfrompem?view=net-6.0), the first parameter is the text of the PEM-encoded X509 certificate, and the second parameter is the text of the PEM-encoded private key.